# Limits in Laplace Transformation2

Tags: laplace-transform

I am given $f(t) = t^2e^{-2t}$ for the Laplace transform. I used IBP twice resulting in

$$[t^2e^{-t(s+2)}-\frac{1}{2}te^{-t(s+2)}-\frac{1}{(s+2)}e^{-t(s+2)}]_0^{\infty}$$

First, is my IBP wrong?
Second, how do I take the limit (I am reviewing limits now).

I was taught that its $b-a$ for limits. Since $b=\infty$ wouldn they all go to infinity?

But if I plug in $0$ for $t$ then we have $\frac{1}{s+2}$ which is wrong! So what do I do?

Comment: Your integration results are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of classical methods:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{t^{2} \, e^{-a t}\} &= \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{2} \, e^{-(a+s) t} \, dt \\
&= \left[- t^{2} \, \frac{e^{-(a+s) t}}{s+a} \right]_{0}^{\infty} + \frac{2}{s+a} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} t \, e^{-(a+s) t} \, dt \\
&= (-1)\left[t^{2} \, \frac{e^{-(a+s) t}}{s+a} + \frac{2 \, t \, e^{-(a+s) t}}{(s+a)^2} \right]_{0}^{\infty} + \frac{2}{(s+a)^2} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(a+s) t} \, dt \\ 
&= (-1)\left[t^{2} \, \frac{e^{-(a+s) t}}{s+a} + \frac{2 \, t \, e^{-(a+s) t}}{(s+a)^2} + \frac{2 \, e^{-(a+s) t}}{(s+a)^3} \right]_{0}^{\infty} \\
&= \frac{2}{(s+a)^3}
\end{align}

A faster method:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{t^{2} \, e^{-a t}\} &= \partial_{s}^{2} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(a+s) t} \, dt = \partial_{s}^{2} \, \left(\frac{1}{s+a} \right) \\
&= \frac{2}{(s+a)^{3}}
\end{align}

Laplace transform property:
$$\mathcal{L}\{t^{n} \, e^{-a t} \, f(t), s \} = (-1)^{n} \, \partial_{s}^{n} \, \mathcal{L}\{f(t), s+a\}.$$

Comment: I am confused still on the implementation of $s$ for $2$. Given, the Laplace of ${(2t+1)^3}$ would I replace it all the same? For example: $\int_0^{\infty}{e^{-(a+(2+1)^3)}dt}$? Please respond!

Comment: Yes, and where does the $(-1)$ come from? And why is it $-t^2$?