# Laplace Transformation (integration by parts confusion/check)

Tags: laplace-transform

> I am trying to find the answer to the Laplace Transformation where $f(t) = {(2t+1)}^3$

From technique and procedure, we use Integration by Parts twice, with

$$uv - \int_0^{\infty}{vdu}$$
$$mn - \int_0^{\infty}{ndm}$$

Substituting $f(t)$ we have

$$\left[-\frac{{(2t+1)}^3e^{-st}}{s}\right]_{0}^{\infty} +\frac{6(2t+1)}{s}\int_0^{\infty}{e^{-st}{(2t+1)^2}}dt$$

$$(-1)\left[\frac{{(2t+1)}^3e^{-st}}{s} +\frac{6(2t+1)^2}{s^2}\right]_{0}^{\infty} +\frac{24(2t+1)e^{-st}}{s^2}\int_0^{\infty}{e^{-st}{(2t+1)}}dt$$

Is this correct so far, and I just take the last integrand? And make sure to carry the $(-1)$ down.

Edit: what i think is that $\frac{24(2t+1)e^{-st}}{s^2}$ leans more towards 
$$\frac{48te^{-st}}{s^3}\int_0^{\infty}{e^{-st}}dt$$

I am using the reference [Limits in Laplace Transformation2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368357/limits-in-laplace-transformation2)

without substituting the $a$. If I could have guidence to that for this particular case, it would be helpful. Perhaps I could apply that to more problems (as for the case in the link).

Answer (score 0):

I would just expand the cube and evaluate the 4 terms.
$$
(2t+1)^3=1 + 6 t + 12 t^2 + 8 t³
$$
$$
\mathcal{L}_t\left((2 t+1)^3\right)\left[s \right]=\frac{48}{s^4}+\frac{24}{s^3}+\frac{6}{s^2}+\frac{1}{s}
$$